# What is the creature in the Shazam mid-credits scene?

Tags: dc, character-identification, dc-extended-universe, shazam-2019

In the mid-sections credit for the *Shazam* movie,

> A caterpillar is talking to Thaddeus Sivana when he is locked in his prison cell.

We see this same creature very early on in the movie,

> When the younger Sivana first enters the original Shazam's cave.

What is this creature and its significance in the DC universe?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I haven't seen the picture you're talking about, but I'm going to take a shot in the dark and guess that your "caterpillar" is that famous Golden Age villain, **Mister Mind**. Quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mister_Mind_and_the_Monster_Society_of_Evil) (with added links):

> **Mister Mind** is a fictional character, a comic book supervillain created for Fawcett Comics, and now owned and published by DC Comics. Created by [Otto Binder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otto_Binder) and [C. C. Beck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C._C._Beck), Mister Mind first appeared as a voice only in [*Captain Marvel Adventures #22*](https://comicbookplus.com/?dlid=70450); his first true appearance was in [*Captain Marvel Adventures* #26 (August 1943)](https://archive.org/details/Captain_Marvel_Adventures_026/page/n53).
>   
> One of Captain Marvel's primary villains, Mister Mind is a two-inch alien worm of high intelligence. Mind usually carries out his villainous plans through an organization called the **Monster Society of Evil**, significant as one of the first supervillain teams in comics to contain villains that a superhero had fought previously; prior to this, supervillain teams were composed of villains created just for that storyline. The Monster Society made its debut in [*Captain Marvel Adventures #22*](https://comicbookplus.com/?dlid=70450), and the resulting "Monster Society of Evil" story arc continued for two years in *Captain Marvel Adventures*, ending with [issue #46](https://archive.org/stream/Captain_Marvel_Adventures_046_1945-05#page/n23/mode/2up).

This is what Mister Mind looked like, taken from the last link.

[image: Comic panels showing Mister Mind]

Comment: This (SPOILER about the possible plot of Shazam 2!!) seems to confirm your theory: https://goo.gl/dbQCdV

Comment: Wow, an evil caterpillar bent on world domination and a bipedal, suit-wearing crocodile. Comic books are weird!

Comment: Also note that Herkimer (the alien Crocodile-Man from the planet Punkus seen above), or at least beings like him, are seen in one of the doors that the kids open near the end of the film. The character was re-imagined as Sobek in the post-52 version of Shazam. He's not yet (I don't believe) appeared in the latest iteration - anyone?